# Block %%% in MySql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a simple website at home for educational purposes and I´m using PHP and MySql.
I have a database with wifi-networks (from wardriving) and i can search the database for SSID-names and see if the network is in my database.
But i noticed that if i enter %%% in my search i get All the results in the database, how can i stop this?

My code is: (edited a little bit for this post to remove sensitive stuff)

```
    <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="search" name="query" placeholder="Sök efter ditt SSID"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sök" />
    </form>
    <?php

    include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/connect.php"; 

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $db_tb_name="database";
    $db_tb_atr_name="ssid";

    $query = str_replace('%', '\%', mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['query']));

    //If search is longer than x characters... 
    if(strlen($query) >= 3) 
        {
        //Do mysql query for results
        $query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE $db_tb_atr_name like '%".$query."%'");

        //If query finds nothing, search is not in databse, echo...
        if (mysql_num_rows($query_for_result) < 1) 
            {
            echo "<br /><h3>Ditt SSID finns inte med i databasen</h3>";
            }
        //Else echo table and populate with results 
        else
            {   
            echo "<br>";
            $num_result = mysql_num_rows($query_for_result);
            echo "<h3>Resultat av sökningen - $num_result träffar</h3>";
            echo "<table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SSID</th>
                <th>MAC</th>
                <th>Kanal</th>
                <th>Kryptering</th>
                <th>Algoritm</th>
                <th>Autentisering</th>
                <th>Signalstyrka</th>
                <th>Tillverkare</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>";

            while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
                {
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . substr($data_fetch[ssid], 0,32) . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . substr($data_fetch[mac], 0,32) . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . substr($data_fetch[channel], 0,32) . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . substr($data_fetch[privacy], 0,32) . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . substr($data_fetch[ciper], 0,32) . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . substr($data_fetch[auth], 0,32) . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . substr($data_fetch[power], 0,32) . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . substr($data_fetch[manuf], 0,32) . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                }
            echo "</table>";
            }               
        }
    //If search is shorter than x characters, echo...
    else 
        { 
        echo "<br /><h3>Sökningen måste innehålla minst 3 tecken</h3>";
        }
    }
     include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/close_connection.php";          
    ?>
```

Comment: Convert $query special chars to their html entity

Comment: `str_replace('%', '\%', $query)`, basically. % is not escaped by m_r_e_s().

Comment: For the love of all things holy, please use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` functions as they will be removed from the next PHP version

Comment: Yep, working on that, someday ;D This is only on my home LAN so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) documentation:

```
Character   Description
%   Matches any number of characters, even zero characters
_   Matches exactly one character
```

Therefor you'll have to escape them in your $query variable.

```
$query = str_replace(array('%', '_'), array('\%', '\_'), mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']));
```

However, I do not suggest you still use the mysql_* functions, as of PHP 5.5.0 the mysql_* functions are deprecated. I suggest you therefor take a look at [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.

I know you mentioned this was for educational purposes and you might already be aware of this, but I still wanted to point it out.

Comment: Nice, this works!

Yes the more i have been reading I´m starting to notice the "old way" is no longer good to use, I am planning to change this soon.

I am only sending the query to the same page, is this still a problem?

Comment: Kind of assumed yout $_GET['query'] was the complete query, which does not seem to be the case. So that wouldn't really be a big problem. However, I still want to advise you to use POST as a method on your form instead. You don't want to end up sending passwords through your url eventually.

Comment: Ok, changed it to POST now. I can no longer search for %%%, however three _ give me all the results instead :/

Comment: Done! I guess it have something to do with: like '%".$query."%'" since this is matching Anything + Search + Anything !?

Comment: Well, you still have to escape the other wildcard, which is "_". Check out my updated answer.